# Why the find cmd is not working inside /sys/class?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, arch-linux, find

I was looking for this file:
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
So I tried searching for it using this cmd:

```
sudo find /sys -name "brightness"
```

But it doesn't find it. I can go in the folder and run it, it will still not find it. It finds a whole bunch of brightness file but not the one in /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight.

```
unkn0wn@archie{~}:sudo find /sys -name "brightness"
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/input0::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/input0::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/input0::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinkvantage/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::thinklight/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::standby/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/leds/tpacpi::power/brightness
```

Why?

Comment: It works fine on my Debian and Arch.

Comment: Strange... Edited my post with the output

Comment: Post some proof that the file actually exists?

Comment: It does change the brightness of my screen when I modify the value of this file and I have a shorcut set on this...
unkn0wn@archie{~}:cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness 
50

Comment: I've noticed that "find /sys/class/backlight/eeepc-wmi" doesn't work but "find /sys/class/backlight/eeepc-wmi/" (slash on the end) does work.

Comment: Your find did locate `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness` isn't this another name for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man find`:

```
-P    Never follow symbolic links. This is the default behavior.  ...
-L    Follow symbolic links.
```

`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` is a symbolic link, so it is not followed.  The actual file is found instead at its physical path, as Zoredache noted in the comments.

Note that you are probably better off with `find`'s default behavior here, as attempting `sudo find -L /sys -name "brightness"` results in infinite errors reading `File system loop detected`.